# How to use Latin accented letters on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having trouble when I try to use letter like á, ó, ú, on Android. In the place of the letters, appear a little strange simbol with a ?, and I can't think of anything to change this. On the Eclipse, the letter appear normally. I'm using Android 1.5.

Comment: Sounds like the font on the phone doesn't have those characters.

Comment: There's a way to add those characters on the phone?

Comment: It should be in the [standard Android font](http://www.ascendercorp.com/pdf/Droid_fonts.pdf). To change your font, you can use something like [Font Changer](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/font-changer-lets-you-change-android-fonts/), but I'm pretty sure you need to have your device rooted for it to work.

Comment: But all Droid fonts on that site have the characters I need. Like á, à, Ú, é, ê, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue reported regarding display of some unicode chars in Android [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=507)